# Adding a play pause toggle to a unity scrubber

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider

So I've got a slider that shows the current place of an animation in unity, you can move the slider to affect the position of the animation. What I'd like to do it add a play pause toggle button to the slider.

I figured you could add the toggle then change the toggle output to 1 or 0 and then multiply the animation speed by 0 or 1 to play or pause the animation, and also this wouldn't change the speed of the animation if it's adjusted elsewhere.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class NewAnimController : MonoBehaviour {

public Slider sliderScrubber;    
public Animator animator;
public Toggle playPause;

private float speed = 1f;
private float playToggle;

public void Update()
{
    float animationTime = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime;
    Debug.Log("animationTime (normalized) is " + animationTime);
    sliderScrubber.value = animationTime;
}

public void OnValueChanged(float changedValue)
{
    animator.speed = speed;   //This is in here to make a slider in the future that changes the speed for a prefab
    animator.Play("Take 001", -1, sliderScrubber.normalizedValue);
}

public void PlayPauseToggle()
{
    if(playPause.isOn)
    {
        playToggle = 1;
    }

    else
    {
        playToggle = 0;
    }
}

 public void NewSpeed(float newSpeed)
{
  speed = newSpeed * playToggle;
}

}
```

This doesn't work, I'm unsure as to why. :/
Am I just going about this the wrong way?

FOR ANYONE THAT NEEDS IT, THIS IS THE WORKING CODE.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class NewAnimController : MonoBehaviour {

public Slider sliderScrubber;
public Slider speedSlider; 
public Animator animator;

private float rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt;

public void Update()
{
    float animationTime = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime;
    Debug.Log("animationTime (normalized) is " + animationTime);
    sliderScrubber.value = animationTime;
}

public void ScrubSliderChanged(float ScrubSliderchangedValue)
{
    animator.Play("Take 001", -1, sliderScrubber.normalizedValue);
}

public void SpeedSliderChanged(float SpeedSliderchangedValue)
{
    animator.speed = speedSlider.normalizedValue;
}


public void UserClickedPauseButton()
{
    if (animator.speed > 0f)
    {
        // we need to pause animator.speed
        rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt = animator.speed;
        animator.speed = 0f;
    }
    else
    {
        // we need to "unpause"
        animator.speed = rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Note - I removed `public Toggle playPause;` from your final code - you should do that in your project!  can cause woes

Comment: Yeah I removed that when I saw it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"OnValueChanged" is not an ideal name because it could refer to anything!  In fact, make TWO different functions with descriptive names.  Have each slider, *only go it its own routine* - don't send them to the same routine.

Note too you are not actually using 'changedValue' - if Im not mistaken you can just remove that.  Don't forget you'll have to re-drag everything in the editor after making the code change

```
public void ScrubSliderChanged()
 {
 animator.Play("Take 001", -1, sliderForScrubber.normalizedValue);
 }
public void SpeedSliderChanged()
 {
 animator.speed = sliderForSpeed.normalizedValue;
 }
```

Regarding the pause, fortunately it couldn't be easier:

you don't really need the bool variable, just do this to get started.

IF YOU WANT A PAUSE BUTTON (not actually a "Toggle" control)

```
private float rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt;
public void UserClickedPauseButton()
  {
  if ( animator.speed > 0f )
   {
   // we need to pause animator.speed
   rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt = animator.speed;
   animator.speed = 0f;
   }
  else
   {
   // we need to "unpause"
   animator.speed = rememberTheSpeedBecauseWeMightNeedIt;
   }
  }
```

TOGGLE CONTROL EXAMPLE CODE

Note to future googlers, **do not use a toggle for a pause button**. Use a UI.Button for a pause button. I only include this as an example of how to use a toggle .. it's just `.isOn`

```
public void UserClickedPauseToggle()
  {
  if ( yourToggle.isOn )
   // code for when toggle is 'on'
  else
   // code for when toggle is 'off'
  }
```

Comment: I'd prefer the button to be a toggle because it's cleaner in the gui. I'll give this a go and see how it plays out :D

Comment: Ok, so this works. BUT there's a slight issue, I can't move the scrubbing slider whilst it's paused, if it's dragged to a new position it jumps back to where it was instead of staying at the new position.

Comment: Was eating lunch, time to answer all previous questions. I've linked up the new sliders, I've checked the drag area, there is no NewSpeed anymore, and how would I do it with a button then changes states from play to pause, I chose a toggle because I can just make the sprites a play and pause icon respectively and it'll switch between them?

Comment: I'm a dummy. I fixed it. Didn't have the right things chosen in the inspector. Here's your points :D

Comment: Hardly a dummy!  it's great to get in to a new programming system. Enjoy yourself. Thanks for the Tick - I live for those!

Comment: Stuck with the button, going to play around with getting it to change from a play icon to a pause icon now, things are slowly coming together thanks to you. :D

Comment: lol enjoy, dont forget a new question if you have button image woes.  cheers